# How to update a custom formula inside google spredsheets automatically without loosing cells around?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hello guys I am trying to receive crypto prices by using Googles Spreadsheet Formula, putting a Formula into google spreadsheets works just fine and I am getting the prices without any problems.

```
 =IMPORTXML("https://www.marketscreener.com/quote/cryptocurrency/BITCOIN-EURO-45553925/";"//td[@class='fvPrice colorBlack']")
```

The Problem: Custom Formulas like IMPORTXML do not update automatically in the spreadsheet, so I grabbed every method from google which does this task, none of them which worked. Until I found one that works partially, it does the job but unfortunately deletes the cells around my formula.

This is my spreadsheet before running the method [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vby3l.png)

This is my spreadsheet after running the method [After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLd1Z.png)

And this is the method that partially works:

```
/**
 * Get all sheet names from active spreadsheet
 */
function sheetNames() {
  var sheetNames = [];
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++) sheetNames.push( sheets[i].getName() )
  return sheetNames;
}

/**
 * Update all formula data in cell range
 */
function updateData() {
    var spreadsheet     = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
        activeSheet     = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet()
        activeSheetName = activeSheet.getSheetName(),
        activeRange     = activeSheet.getActiveRange(),
        sheets          = sheetNames() // OR define an array of sheet names: ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2'],
      //  cellRange       = (activeRange.getValues().length > 1) ? activeRange.getA1Notation() : Browser.inputBox('Enter your range'),
        range           = '';
                
    // loop through all sheets
    sheets.forEach(function(sheet) {
        var originalFormulas = [],
            range            = activeRange,
            defaultRanges    = {
                'europeList': 'A1:F9',
                'europeList': 'A1:F9'
            },
        
        // set cell range if entered, ortherwise fall back to default
        cellRange = defaultRanges[sheet];
        
        // set range to active range, otherwise fall back to defined cell range
        range = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(sheet).getRange(cellRange);
        
        originalFormulas = range.getFormulas();
            
        // modify formulas
        const modified = originalFormulas.map(function (row) {
            return row.map(function (col) { 
              return col.replace('=', '?');
            }); 
        });
        
        // update formulas
        range.setFormulas(modified);
        SpreadsheetApp.flush();
        
        // return formulas to original
        range.setFormulas(originalFormulas);
    });
}
```

Anyone got a idea, how to fix this?

Comment: What have you missed? Why does it target other cells?? Where are they referenced? Which cells in particular? Then find them in your code...

Comment: And why doesn’t your title match the body of the question?

Comment: I have added a before after picture, which exactly shows the issue, there is a originalFormulas property which should store the values and then later reflushe them, makes sense to me, so I just cant figure out why this happens

Comment: you can force a reset with ```function refresh() { SpreadsheetApp.flush() }``` and set this on a time trigger. Or look at this script i wrote fore the CoinMarketCap API. https://www.reddit.com/r/sheets/comments/o7h6db/im_needing_help_modifying_script_to_accommodate/

Comment: I still don't understand, if you are getting the prices, what is wrong? They do update automatically too, just not very quickly. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the script.